# Max size of stylesheet

Tags: css

Could someone tell how big a single stylesheet can get (in kb or mb) before it begins to slow down the webpage.

Thanks

Comment: This question is completely unanswerable. There are far, far too many variables involved. What is the size/complexity of the DOM? What browser is being used? What are the specs of the computer it's running on?

Comment: This question is not a good fit to our Q&A format. We expect answers to generally involve facts, references, or specific expertise; this question will likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion.

Comment: The answer to this question is not quantitative and therefore not a good fit for StackOverflow. However, you should check out a tool like [Yahoo's YSlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/) or [Google's Page Speed Online](https://developers.google.com/pagespeed/) in order to get some feedback on potential performance issues with your site.

Comment: While we're at it, how many licks does it take to reach the tootsie roll center of a tootsie pop?

Comment: There are limits if you care about IE8. There's a [4096 rule limit](http://hjzhao.blogspot.co.uk/2011/11/ie8-css-file-4096-rule-limit.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such defined limit that larger than this css file will make the webpage slower. For general use, it is not really a limitation, unless it is a special case. jQuery and I am sure others frameworks have big CSS files and it is ok.